# Error serializing Next.js in getStaticProps function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I'm using `getStaticProps()` function and I get this error for no reason:

> Error: Error serializing `.posts[0]` returned from `getStaticProps` in
> "/". Reason: `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as
> JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.

I'm also using a mongoDb database, the `connectDb()` function runs the `mongoose.connect()` function and connects to the database. also, the `console.log()`s return valid JSON format data, I don't know what is causing this issue, here is my code:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (
  context: GetStaticPropsContext
) => {
  await connectDb()
  const count = await PostModel.countDocuments()
  const posts = await PostModel.find()
  console.log(posts)
  console.log(count)
  return {
    props: { posts: posts, count: count },
    revalidate: 10,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) it will convert in a plain JavaScript object.

```
const posts = await PostModel.find().lean();
```

or you can try serialization via [.toJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior)